# How to Find Groups Based on uids by when using two different ArrayLists?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

Using Java 1.8 and Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE.

Am able to obtain a list of items from by parsing /etc/passwd and /etc/group inside an ArrayList & ArrayList.

---

Need to create the following Rest Endpoint:

```
HTTP GET /users/<uid>/groups
```

Return all the groups for a given user.

---

User:

```
public class User {

    String name;
    String password;
    Integer uid;
    Integer gid;
    String comment;
    String home;
    String shell;

    public User(String line) {
        String[] items = line.split(":");

        if (items.length != 7) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need 7 items from " + line + " and there's only: " + items.length);
        }

        this.name = items[0];
        this.password = items[1];
        this.uid = Integer.parseInt(items[2]);
        this.gid = Integer.parseInt(items[3]);
        this.comment = items[4];
        this.home = items[5];
        this.shell = items[6];
    }

    // Getters & Setters omitted for brevity.
}
```

Group:

```
public class Group {
    private Integer gid;
    private String name;
    private List<String> members;

    public Group(String line) {
        String[] items = line.split(":");

        this.name = items[0];
        this.gid = Integer.parseInt(items[2]);

        if (items.length > 3){
            this.members = Arrays.asList(items[3]);
        }
    }   

    // Getters & Setters omitted for brevity.
}
```

FileParserUtils:

```
public class FileParserUtils {

    public static List<Group> parseFileForGroups(String line) {
        List<Group> groups = null;
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(line))) {

            groups = stream.filter(s -> s.charAt(0) != '#').map(Group::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return groups;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {   

    @Override
    public User findByUid(String line, Integer uid) {
        List<User> allUsers = FileParserUtils.parseFileForUsers(line);
        for (User user : allUsers) {
            if (user.getUid() == uid) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Group> findByGroupsByUid(String line, Integer uid) {
        User specificUser = findByUid(line, uid);
        Integer userGid = specificUser.getGid();        
        List<Group> allGroups = FileParserUtils.parseFileForGroups(line);
        List<Group> userGroups = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Group group : allGroups) {
            if (userGid == group.getGid()) {
                userGroups.add(group);
            }
        }
        return userGroups;
    }
}
```

---

This issue is that not all User uids are the same as the Group's gids (see the  gids & uids for `"name":"_cyrus"`):

Obtain a list of Users (along with their uids & gids):

```
HTTP GET /myservice/users:
```

Yields JSON Payload Response:

```
[  
    {  
        "name":"_cyrus",
        "password":"*",
        "uid":77,
        "gid":6,
        "comment":"Cyrus Administrator",
        "home":"/var/imap",
        "shell":"/usr/bin/false"
    },
    {  
        "name":"_mailman",
        "password":"*",
        "uid":78,
        "gid":78,
        "comment":"Mailman List Server",
        "home":"/var/empty",
        "shell":"/usr/bin/false"
    },
    {  
        "name":"_appserver",
        "password":"*",
        "uid":79,
        "gid":79,
        "comment":"Application Server",
        "home":"/var/empty",
        "shell":"/usr/bin/false"
    },
    {
        "name": "_jabber",
        "password": "*",
        "uid": 84,
        "gid": 84,
        "comment": "Jabber XMPP Server",
        "home": "/var/empty",
        "shell": "/usr/bin/false"
    }
]
```

Groups only have gids (and not uids):

```
[
    {
        "gid": 6,
        "name": "mail",
        "members": [
            "_teamsserver"
        ]
    }
    {
        "gid": 78,
        "name": "_mailman",
        "members": null
    },
    {
        "gid": 79,
        "name": "_appserverusr",
        "members": null
    },
    {
        "gid": 30,
        "name": "_keytabusers",
        "members": [
          "_calendar,_jabber,_postfix"
        ]
    }

]
```

So, when if I try to find all the groups that Jabber belongs to:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyService/users/84/groups
```

Get the following JSON Response Payload:

```
[
    {
        "gid": 84,
        "name": "_jabber",
        "members": [
            "84",
            "Jabber XMPP Server",
            "/var/empty",
            "/usr/bin/false"
        ]
    }
]
```

Why is 84 inside the members JSON array?

This is supposed to return all groups for the given user:

```
[   
    {
        "gid": 29,
        "name": "certusers",
        "members": [
          "root,_jabber,_postfix,_cyrus,_calendar,_dovecot"
        ]
    },
    {
        "gid": 30,
        "name": "_keytabusers",
        "members": [
          "_calendar,_jabber,_postfix"
        ]
    }
]
```

---

Is there a way to map (e.g. link the two ArrayLists together or is there a different data structure that would help me do this) the User.uids with Group.gids?

This is all in-memory so please don't mention the use of ORM or JDBC.

Comment: Where do these two desired groups come from? How do you determine that jabber is part of these two groups, (one of which doesn't even exist in the list of groups that you posted)?

Comment: They come from an ArrayList which was populated by me parsing the /etc/group file on Unix / Linux.

Comment: What is the answer to my second question? You get the uid of a user. How do you find the groups that the user belongs to?

Comment: @JBNizet - I have a HTTP GET call that give me all the users and inside each individual user there's a gid and uid. Its the gid that I use inside my code (see above). I edited the post to answer your question...

Comment: OK. So that means that if you pass the uid 84, then the user is the one named "_jabber". The gid of this user is also 84. So that means _jabber has a single group identified by the gid 84 (which is not present in the posted list of groups). So, the result you have is correct. Why do you expect another result containing the groups 29 and 30 then?

Comment: @JBNizet - I revised my post - please see that the groups for "_jabber" is not giving me all the groups that "_jabber" to...

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. Let's ask it again. If I ask you to find the groups for the user identified by the uid 84, tell me how you find them. Without writing code. Just explain me how you do it, in your head. You told me before that the answer is the group 84, because that's the gid of the uder whose uid is 84. But you also tell me that this is not the answer you expect. So, how do you actully find the groups?

Comment: No, I don't chat. You can answer here.

Comment: @JBNizet - I revised my post and added FileParserUtils - that's how I parse the /etc/group file and populated an ArrayList<Group>, please see GroupServiceImpl.findByGroupsByUid(String line, Integer uid) method that I posted above.

To explain in layman's terms: 

1. Parse the contents of /etc/passwd & /etc/groups and place both of them in ArrayLists.

2. Do a Rest Call to get a list of all the users and groups.

3. Check for groups inside my . findByGroupsByUid(String line, Integer uid) method. Something seems rather off because I want a list of groups that belong to the uid.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. Forget about code, parsing, or whatever. You have the list of users on a piece of paper, written exactly as you posted them in your question. You have the list of groups on another piece of papers, written exactly as you posted them in your question. I ask you "what are the groups of the user identified by 84". You look at your two pieces of paper, and answer me "they are the groups 29 and 30". What I need to know is: how did you find that answer? How do you know that the answer is "29 and 30"?

Comment: @JBNizet - Ran a REST call that gave me all groups using Swagger and did a control-F inside the browser to look for "_jabber" inside the JSON's member response.

Comment: OK. So, to find the group of the user with the UID 84, you find the name of this user in the list of users. That gives you "_jabber". And then you loop through all the groups, and as long as any property of a group  contains "_jabber", then the user belongs to that group? So if the `name` of the group is "foo_jabber_bar", it's one of the groups? And if the `members` property property of the group is `["_calendar,foo_jabberbar,_postfix"]`, then it's one of the groups, too?

Comment: I don't know about foo_jabberbar - I am just saying that _jabber is uid is 84 so it should be easy to search for that by seeing if User.getUid = Group.getGid. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm trying to help you find the solution here. If you don't know how to find the groups, you can't implement the correct algorithm. And if you think that you must code the equivalent of Ctrl-F for the user name, then being able to test for User.getUid = Group.getGid won't help at all. Neither user.uid nor group.gid contains the name of the user. So these two algorithms would give completely different answers. And none of them would be the right one. You're contradicting yourself constantly.

Comment: Anyway, whatever the actual criteria used to find the answer is, the structure of the algoritghm is always the same: loop through the groups, test if the group matches the criteria. If it does, add it to the result. You just need to finally decide what the criteria are.

Comment: If you look at my code you should be able to understand the criteria, I am just seeking advice on why its not working.

Comment: It's not working because it's the wrong criteria. Hence the question I keep asking.